# MySQL: Having AND condition on the same column

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask if it's possible to have a AND condition for the same column?

The reason why I need to do this is to have an exact result for our query.

Sample Table:

```
+=====================================+
|                recipe               |
+-------------------------------------+
| ID |  name | description | servings |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1  | Adobo | N/A         |    6     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 2  | S.P.C | N/A         |    5     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 3  | Kare2 | N/A         |    6     |
+=====================================+

+============================+
|     recipe_ingredients     |
+----------------------------+
| ID | recipe_id |    name   |
+----------------------------+
| 1  |     1     |    Pork   |
+----------------------------+
| 2  |     1     | Soy Sauce |
+----------------------------+
| 3  |     1     |   Garlic  |
+----------------------------+
| 4  |     2     |   Garlic  |
+----------------------------+
| 5  |     2     |   Onion   |
+----------------------------+
| 6  |     3     |  Vinegar  |
+----------------------------+
```

Some recipe have the same ingredient(s) but when I query, I need only to get the recipe based on the exact ingredients I've given. Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
tbl_recipe.name, tbl_recipe.description, tbl_recipe.user_name,
tbl_ingredients.ingredient_name, tbl_ingredients.ingredient_measure_type, tbl_ingredients.ingredient_measure_value
FROM recipes AS tbl_recipe
LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients AS tbl_ingredients
ON tbl_ingredients.recipe_id = tbl_recipe.id
WHERE tbl_ingredients.ingredient_name IN ('Garlic', 'Soy Souce')
```

**It returns:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|      name         | description | tbl_ingredients.name   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Traditional Adobo |     N/A     |       Soy Souce        |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Traditional Adobo |     N/A     |       Garlic           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|      S.P.C        |     N/A     |       Garlic           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|      name         | description | tbl_ingredients.name   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Traditional Adobo |     N/A     |       Soy Souce        |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Traditional Adobo |     N/A     |       Garlic           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is I only need the **Traditional Adobo** returned since I want my WHERE query to be exact on the recipe's ingredient(s).

Your help is highly appreciated thanks!

Comment: looking at the data and your requirements, your database structure is wrong. You have implemented `one to many` relationship, instead you have a `many to many` relation. One `Recipe` can have many `ingredients` and one `ingredient` could be used in many `Recipe`s.

Comment: What you want it's known as division, you want all the receips that contain all the ingredients you want. You can do this by do the oposite of what you want your query to do, and then select all that are not in the past selection (just wait a bit and I'll give you the query)

Comment: @ankit: I see, thanks, I'll also consider to change my table relationship.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, what you want is called a division in relational algebra. There's actually a lot of ways to do this (you can do a kick search on the web).

Here's one of the ways I found to do what you want:

```
SELECT tbl_recipe.name
FROM recipes AS tbl_recipe
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT tbl_ingredients.ingredient_name
    FROM recipe_ingredients AS tbl_ingredients
    WHERE ingredient_name IN ('Garlic', 'Soy Souce')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT R.name
        FROM recipes AS R
        LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredients AS I
        ON I.recipe_id = R.id
        WHERE R.id = tbl_recipe.ID AND I.recipe_id = tbl_recipe.recipe_id));
```

Note, query just returns all the receips that have all those ingredients (Garlic and Soy Souce). You can manipulate the query to return other things like description of the recipe ... This is just an idea.
The idia behind this query (so that you can understand it easier) is that what you are searching is the same as searching for each recipe you want to check that there's no ingredient that is not used for that recipe.

P.S: I didn't check the query, but the idea is there.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer, I get the concept of your query.
But what I like to achieve is to only return the result of the exact ingredients that I searched.

eg: I want to search for a recipe that have "garlic" and "soy sauce" as its ingredients **only** nothing less, nothing more.

What that be possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can join the ingredients table multiple times for each ingredient.
Assuming you placed the ingredients in a separate table and recipe_ingredients is the link table:

```
SELECT
    r.name,
    r.description,
    CONCAT(i1.name, ',',  i2.name) ingredients
FROM
    recipe r
JOIN
    recipe_ingredients ri
    ON r.ID = ri.recipe_id
JOIN
    ingredients i1
    ON ri.ingredient_id = i1.id AND i1.name = 'Soy sauce'
JOIN
    ingredients i2
    ON ri.ingredient_id = i2.id AND i2.name = 'Garlic'
LEFT JOIN
    ingredients i3
    ON ri.ingredient_id = i3.id AND i3.name NOT IN ('Soy sauce', 'Garlic')
WHERE
    i3.id IS NULL
```

With the left join and i3.id IS NULL condition (anti-join), recipes with only those two ingredients will be returned